# Armazenar respostas de um quiz com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando criar um quiz e gostaria de saber como eu crio uma função para armazenar as respostas usando javascript. Posso armazenar em um array para depois fazer a comparação se estão certas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <body>
    <form class="formulario">
      <div class="question">
        <p>Quem foi o campeão brasileiro de 2016?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" id="op1">Palmeiras<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="4" id="op2">Flamengo<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" id="op3">Grêmio<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="3" id="op4">Cruzeiro<br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: De onde vêm as perguntas? estás a carregar uma pergunta por página ou estás a usar ajax?

Comment: Eu quero que seja uma pergunta por página, mas primeiro preciso saber como armazenar as respostas. No caso do código que eu postei, qual função usar para armazenar a resposta e verificar se está correta?

Comment: Qual é a linguagem que tens no servidor? e sabes o que é ajax e json?

Comment: Eu estou a fazer perguntas para perceber melhor o contexto da aplicação e para podermos dar uma resposta mais útil.

Comment: Estou usando somente javascript, e não conheço ainda ajax e json.